# C++: Is It OK to Inherit from a Class and Its Protected Member Type?

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, protected

Is the following code C++ standard compliant?

```
struct B
{
protected:
    struct Type {};
};

struct D : B, B::Type
{};

int main()
{
    D d;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried it on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/).
MSVC(VS 2017 RTW) accepts it.
gcc(7.3) and clang(6.0.0) reject it.

Comment: Dunno, but you have demonstrated that you can't rely on the behavior regardless of what the standard says, so don't. One workaround is to just use two levels of class derivation (inheritance).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The code is standard compliant and was since C++11, but was not in C++03.

C++11 through C++17 say this in the introduction to section [class.access] , Member Access Control:

> All access controls in clause [class.access] affect the ability to access a class member name from the declaration of a particular entity, including parts of the declaration preceding the name of the entity being declared and, if the entity is a class, the definitions of members of the class appearing outside the class's *member-specification*.

In those same Standard versions, an example follows which is very much like your question, but even a bit trickier:

> [Example:
>
> ```
>   class A {
> ...
>   protected:
>       struct B { };
>   };
> ...
>
>   struct D: A::B, A { };
> ```
>
> ... The use of `A::B` as a *base-specifier* is well-formed because `D` is derived from `A`, so checking of *base-specifiers* must be deferred until the entire *base-specifier-list* has been seen. -*end example*]

But I see the same results you did: g++ and clang++ both reject these programs, no matter what `-std=` argument I give.  This is a pair of compiler bugs.

C++03 has this instead of the first paragraph I quoted above:

> All access controls in clause [class.access] affect the ability to access a class member name from a particular scope.  The access control for names used in the definition of a class member that appears outside of the member's class definition is done as if the entire member definition appeared in the scope of the member's class....

The *base-specifier* of a class definition is not in that class's scope, so C++03 does not allow using a protected or private name as the name of a base class for a derived class that otherwise has access to that name.

Comment: Here's another [tricky case](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VhWPp1wqe8vL4gqB), where you would be allowed to inherit from it if only you had already done so.

Comment: @DavisHerring Do you think that program is ill-formed? I'm having trouble seeing why it would be different.

Comment: It falls in the wonderful category of "it's well-formed if and only if it's well-formed": _if_ `C` inherits from `A::B`, then it inherits from `A` and so it is allowed to mention `A::B` to inherit from it.  If it doesn't, it can't.  Either state is self-consistent, and GCC/Clang seem to be doing the common thing of adding a sort of time component (modulo the "deferred" you cited): you "start" with 0 base classes, and there's no path to having 1 under the rules that pertain to having 0.  I don't think there's any unambiguous reading of the wording here.

Comment: @DavisHerring You're using an implied assumption that "if a name in a base-specifier-list is inaccessible, then the class does not inherit the named type".  But this isn't directly supported by the descriptions of base classes or inheritance or member access.  I would say that it's simpler and otherwise always correct to say that member access checks are always orthogonal to all other semantic considerations.  We wouldn't say that a use of an inaccessible member doesn't actually name, odr-use, or call that member...

Comment: ... So why couldn't we say of an ill-formed program that "`Z` inherits `X::Y`, and that use of `X::Y` is ill-formed because the member name is inaccessible"?

Comment: I was a bit surprised by [this test](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Opojm8M18sH6YGzI) which shows that GCC/clang take your interpretation that you do inherit even if it's ill-formed, but I think a careful reading of [class.access]/5 agrees (though it's hard to reason about ill-formed programs within the standard).  I'll still raise the issue with CWG before I (encourage someone to) file bugs with the compilers.

Comment: @DavisHerring Hm, [class.access]/5 reads to me like it supports my conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

If D is derived from B, it has access to its protected members, so this should be correct. The question would be if it has *already* access at that point of compilation, or if it only gets access once the type is complete.

Note that it should fail if you turn the two around (putting B behind the comma).

Comment: In fact it should not fail if the bases are listed in the other order: see my answer.